# Unexpected clustering errors (partitioning around mediods)

Tags: r, nlp, cluster-analysis, k-means, unsupervised-learning

I am using the `fpc` package for determining the optimal number of clusters.   The `pamk()` function takes a dissimilarity matrix as an argument and does not require the user to specify `k`. According to the [documentation](https://rdrr.io/cran/fpc/man/fpc-package.html):

> pamk() This calls pam and clara for the partitioning around medoids
> clustering method (Kaufman and Rouseeuw, 1990) and includes two
> different ways of estimating the number of clusters.

but when I input two very similar matricies - `foo` and `bar` (data below), the function errors out on the second matrix (bar)

```
Error in pam(sdata, k, diss = diss, ...) : 
  Number of clusters 'k' must be in {1,2, .., n-1}; hence n >= 2
```

What could be causing this error, given that the input matricies are basically the same?  For example:

foo works!

```
hc <- hclust(as.dist(foo))
plot(hc)
pamk.best <- fpc::pamk(foo)
pamk.best$nc
[1] 2
```

[image]

bar does not

```
hc <- hclust(as.dist(bar))
plot(hc, main = 'bar dendogram')
pamk.best <- fpc::pamk(bar)
Error in pam(sdata, k, diss = diss, ...) : 
  Number of clusters 'k' must be in {1,2, .., n-1}; hence n >= 2
```

[image]

Any suggestions would be helpful!

```
dput(foo)
structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
9, 9, 9, 9, 0, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
9, 9, 9, 9, 0, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 0), .Dim = c(14L, 14L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("etc", "etc", "etc", "etc", "etc", "etc", "etc", "similares", 
    "etc", "etc", "etc", "etc", "etc", "similares"), NULL))

dput(bar)
structure(c(0, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0), .Dim = c(5L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(c("ramírez", 
"similares", "similares", "similares", "similares"), NULL))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bar` has `n=5` columns, so the `max(krange)` has to be <= n-1, thus 4. The default krange is 2:10, hence the error. You may have to pass an appropriate `krange`; try:

```r
pamk.best <- fpc::pamk(bar, krange=c(2:(dim(bar)[2]-1)))
```